# LogLogPlot with numerical errors and warnings in NIntegrate using fine integrating steps

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I have the following (long) function of `g1` and `ω`that I wish to integrate with respect to `ω`

```
f = (200 (7692800000000 g1^4 (1000000 + ω (100 + ω) (400 + ω (100 + ω))) + 601(44100 - 399 ω^2 + 4 ω^4) (400000001 + 40000 ω (200 + ω)) (396054100 + ω (200 + ω) (79601 + 4 ω (200 + ω))) + 800 g1^2 (165388780876943610000 + ω (9974810249137020000 + ω (338251703143216200 + ω (17987201082240200 + ω (541408115948001 + 4 ω (1956801870100 + ω (13896010001 + 40000 ω (1101 + ω))))))))))/(2560000000000000000 g1^4 (1000000 + ω (100 + ω) (400 + ω (100 + ω))) + (1 + 40000 ω^2) (44100 - 399 ω^2 + 4 ω^4) (400000001 + 40000 ω (200 + ω)) (396054100 + ω (200 + ω) (79601 + 4 ω (200 + ω))) - 3200000000 g1^2 (-83117559000000 + ω (100 + ω) (-17690047067700 + ω (100 + ω) (-5302720399 + 4 ω (100 + ω) (3989599 + 40000 ω (100 + ω))))))
```

I first construct a table and prepend `g1` while integrating with respect to `ω`

```
int = Table[{g1, 1/(2 π)*NIntegrate[f, {ω, -200, 200}]}, {g1, 0, 100}]
```

and I am returned with a bunch of warnings, saying something like

```
"NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in ω near {ω} = {-0.00621666}. NIntegrate obtained 97.19546034578347` and 0.8830472862609543` for the integral and error estimates"
```

Which I ignore since it's just a warning (I don't know if I should trust the results). I then proceed to do a `ListLogLogPlot` of `int` as a function of `g1`

```
plot = ListLogLogPlot[int, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black]}]
```

And I am returned with (ignoring the plot label)[image]

Now I wish to increase my time step, so under my `NIntegrate` I change my integration step to `0.1`

```
int = Evaluate@Table[{g1, 1/(2 π)*NIntegrate[f, {ω, -200, 200}]}, {g1, 1/10, 100, 1/10}]
```

However, the computation time took extremely long and I was returned with this [image]

Clearly, there are some numerics that Mathematica was mishandling in the integration process. I think this might have something to do with the warnings but I'm unsure of how to remedy it. The reason I want to push it to `0.1` was because `LogLogPlot` does not show `g1` starting from `0` since there is no such thing as the Log of 0. So pushing my starting point to `0.1` will bring me close to `0`. In fact, I intend to push my starting point to `0.01` in steps of `0.01` for `g1` but it will take tremendously long. How should I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue)?:

```
int = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {i'[ω] == f/(2 π), i[-200]==0},
    i[200],
    {ω,-200,200},
    g1
]
```

> [image]

Plot:

```
LogLogPlot[int[g], {g, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

Plot with smaller starting value for `g1`:

```
LogLogPlot[int[g], {g, .01, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm studying `ParametricNDSolveValue` as we speak. However, I think there is a mistake on the second plot. When `g1` is close to `0` the curve should start at around 300 but you have it over 1000. Is it because of numerics?

Comment: @kowalski That's because I didn't include the factor of 1/(2π) in the integral.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question: why did you set `i[-200] = 0` followed by `i[200]`? Are you setting a boundary condition? Also the spike at around `g1=30` goes all the way up, to near infinity, is that a pole? It is not the case for the smaller time step setting as shown in my first plot. The spike peaks at 10. Why should the spike peak differently in a smaller integrating step?

Comment: @kowalski The i[-200], i[200] bits are how you translate an integral into a differential equation. Your first plot has a smaller peak because you didn't sample `g1` close enough to the singularity.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to study this `ParametricNDSolveValue` function in detail. This is useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using a higher-order integration rule will reduce the need for recursion when the function is analytic in a (complex) neighborhood of the interval of integration:

```
int = Evaluate@Table[
     {g1, 1/(2 π) NIntegrate[f, {ω, -200, 0, 200}, 
        Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}]},
     {g1, 10.^Subdivide[-2., 2, 100]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.07156, Null}  *)

plot = ListLogLogPlot[int, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Joined -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or:

```
LogLogPlot[1/(2 π)* NIntegrate[f, {ω, -200, 0, 200}, 
   Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}],
 {g1, 0.01, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't have an issue with integrating steps of `g1` from `0` to `100` but rather, from `0.01` to `100` in steps of `0.01`. The latter is computationally intensive and I need a simpler way to do that.

Comment: @kowalski Oops, copied the wrong code. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! That works really well too. I have a quick question, what does `Points -> 21` do? Is it like a `PlotPoints` option? If so, why can't I just put it under the `LogLogPlot` function? The closest that I can find on the documentation is `PlotPoints` and just `Point` which isn't used under `Methods`

Comment: @kowalski It's an option for the [Gauss-Kronrod rule](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#381359375) (and other interpolatory rules) that specifies how many points to use for the underlying Gauss-Legendre method; Kronrod showed how to add points to these that simultaneously approximates both the integral and the error. When the integrand is analytic, the Gauss-Legendre method converges very rapidly as the number of points increases, provided there are at least a couple of points per oscillation.The integrand has very few oscillations....

Comment: The default strategy is a heuristic balance of points (default 5) and subdivision of the interval. The more points the fewer subdivisions and vice versa. Too much of one or the other usually wastes time. Subdivisions can help with oscillatory regions and other odd behavior. One subdivision that certainly helps is `ω == 0` for small `g1`, where there is a narrow spike; that's why I added a `0` between the `±200`.

Comment: I actually had some warnings pertaining to oscillations. Something like "...the existence of highly oscillating integrands..." but I guess there wasn't a lot, like you suggested. I thought there was something special about picking `21` for the points. Thanks for clarifying your solution. Although I certainly did learn something from @Carl Woll about `ParametricNDSolveValue` as well!